# Creating a JSFiddle with Angular-ui-router and multiple views

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle, angular-ui-router

I have a question I would like to ask the community, but am having trouble setting up the required JSFiddle to make it easier to demonstrate the issue. I want to create a fiddle with three views side by side using Angular's [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Seems simple, but for some reason I can't get the views' controller's to initialize. The main app loads, as evidenced by console messages, but I'm stumped.

The Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R9T73/), and for completeness sake, the html and js are here:

HTML:

```
<div ui-view="top" class="top">
  <br />
  $scope.testmsg = {{testmsg}}
  <br />
  $scope.statename = {{statename}}
  <br />
  top!
</div>
<div ui-view="middle" class="middle">middle!</div>
<div ui-view="bottom" class="bottom">bottom!</div>
```

JS:

```
/* myApp module */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        'top': {
            url: "",
            template: '<div>top! {{topmsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.topmsg = "loaded top!";
                console.log("top ctrl!"); // this does NOT show in console
            }
        },
        'middle': {
            url: "",
            template: '<div>middle! {{middlemsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.middlemsg = "loaded middle!";
                console.log("middle ctrl!"); // this does NOT show in console
            }
        },
        'bottom': {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: '<div>bottom! {{bottommsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.bottommsg = "loaded bottom!";
                console.log("bottom ctrl!"); // this does NOT show in console
            }
        }
    },
    onEnter: function () {
        console.log("entered home state"); // this does NOT show in console
    }
  });
}])
.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope, $state/*, $stateParams*/) {
  $scope.statename = $state.current.name;
  $scope.testmsg = "app scope working!";
  console.log("MyAppCtrl initialized!"); // this shows in console
  $state.go("home");
});
```

My body tag has the correct (I believe) references to my app and controller: `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl"></body>`... I'm stuck. Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your only mistake is in the configuration for the `'bottom'` view. You have `templateUrl` instead of `template`. After I made this change in your fiddle, all the controllers initialize correctly.

Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/7tzXh/). But like I said, changing `templateUrl` to `template` is the only change. Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it, thanks so much. Stare at the weeds long enough and I miss stupid things like that. I wonder why there wasn't an error that cropped up complaining about that? I appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes.