# Is it neccessary to write ui-view in div?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
<div ui-view="columnTwo"></div>
```

I dont want my view to bind in div....Is there any alternate solution like dis?

`<ui-view>ColumnOne</ui-view>`

or

```
<ui-view src="ColumnOne"></ui-view>
```

Comment: You mean you just want to pass the data to your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute ui-view directive:

```
<div ui-view="columnTwo">[target of rendering]</div>
```

is equivalent to a named [ui-view element](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view#usage), like this:

```
<ui-view name="columnTwo">[target of rendering]</ui-view>
```

If you want something outside of the target element's contents to change when you change views, then you should be able to rely on the `onload` attribute.

```
<ui-view name="columnTwo" onload="myFun()">[target of rendering]</ui-view>
```

where Myfun will be evaluated in the context of the state->view's scope, but could interact with a parent scope.

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mftgjadm/1/) using the `ui-view` with `name` and `onload` attributes, (using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21393413/1269466) jsfiddle as a starting point.)

Answer (score 1):

No not required  but div can allocate space in DOM to view the data.
Ui-view is a directive and can br used as an element or attribute.

```
<ui-view autoscroll='true'/>
```

or

```
<div ui-view="chart"></div>
```

If you use it as a element you can add only attributes those are defined for ui-view

Comment: My problem is i want that value "columnTwo"  to use in script...how should i get that value without using any html tag...

Comment: I mean is there any possibility to get that like `<ui-view value="columnOne"><ui-view>`

Comment: No thats not possible